# Workflow/design pattern for allowing user to add multiple fields

Tags: website-design, forms, input-fields, microinteractions

**Context:**

I have a page where a user can select from multiple input sources. Within the selected source(s), they can define multiple source links.

**Problem**

The way I have currently structured it is as follows:

[image]

Now, the "Add source" dropdown hold multiple other options. Each that needs different parameters as input. This causes the form to grow really long especially if the user wants to have multiple source inputs.
Is there a solution for such interactions/ examples of how other applications solve such interactions?

Comment: Hi Ashwin. I'm not sure if I've seen anything else exactly like this. I understand that the dropdown my trigger a long section with input fields, but it's not quite clear what your concern about this is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can minimize the form for each source once it has been completed.

This way, the user will only see the list of all sources (type of sources) already contributed and one form for a new source.

The user can go back and edit previous sources by clicking on their type / name.